# Remove menu option for specific selected values?

Tags: tableau-api

Is there a way to remove the option to select a menu link for specific fields?

For example I have a dashboard that has details of each users action and a few of those users are actually an automated system. So the few that are part of the system do not need to be reviewed as those are always automatic.

I want to only allow this menu selection for actual users and not the few "accounts" that are part of an automated system.

The kind of menu link on selection I am talking about.

[image]

[image]

Is it possible to remove this menu link for only specific values in a column?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible - am fascinated to know if someone comes in with a way to do it - so one option to consider is renaming to "Daily Details - ignore for Bot 1 & 2" so the users are aware they should do nothing.

Comment: Well they don't want to give the user the option. I know there is a level of common since involved but that was the request so I am doing what I can to accommodate .